# syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Tags: linux, bash, script

`` menu.sh: line 48: syntax error near unexpected token `)' menu.sh: line 48: `             3) read -p 'pepe' pepe;' ``

```
 !/bin/bash
    
    # Encabezado
    
    RED="31"
    GREEN="32"
    YELLOW: "33"
    yellowcolor="\e[33m"
    BOLDGREEN="\e[1;${GREEN}m"
    ITALICRED="\e[3;${RED}m"
    ENDCOLOR="\e[0m"
    
    echo -e "${BOLDGREEN}XXXXXX${ENDCOLOR}"
    echo -e "${ITALICRED}XXXXXX${ENDCOLOR}"
    
    echo -e "###########################################################################################"
    
    figlet -c Menu de opciones
    
    echo XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | printf "%*s\n" $(( $( tput cols )/2 )) "$(cat /dev/stdin)"
    echo XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | printf "%*s\n" $(( $( tput cols )/2 )) "$(cat /dev/stdin)"
    
    
    echo -e "###########################################################################################"
    
    # Codigo
    
    while [ "$OPCION" != 7 ]
    do
            echo "[1] Crear un usuario nuevo"
            echo "[2] Cambiar la contraseña a un usuario"
            echo "[3] Crear un grupo nuevo"
            echo "[4] Ver datos de un usuario"
            echo "[5] Borrar un usuario del sistema"
            echo "[6] Borrar un grupo"
            echo "[7] Salir del script"
    
            read -p "pepe: " OPCION
    
        case $OPCION in
            1) read -p "[+] Escriba el nombre del usuario: " username
            adduser $username
            echo ""
            echo -e "${BOLDGREEN}El usuario ${ENDCOLOR} ${yellowcolor}$username${ENDCOLOR} 
            ${BOLDGREEN}ha sido creado correctamente  ${ENDCOLOR}"
            echo "";;
            2) read -p "[+] Introduzca el nombre de usuario al que desea cambiar la 
            contraseña: " user
            passwd $user;
            3) read -p "[+] Introduzca el nombre del nuevo grupo:" gpapapap
            addgroup $gpapapap;;
            echo ""
            echo "[+] El grupo - $gpname - ha sido creado correctamente "
            echo ""
            
        esac
    
    done
    exit 0
```

Error al colocar la opción 3 del menú, si lo elimino el script se ejecuta sin problemas. Llevo todo el día atascado, no sé cuál es el problema. He probado cientos de posibilidades pero no encuentro el camino. También he utilizado sed -i
Seguro que es un fallo muy tonto pero estoy empezando y google no me ha ayudado a resolver el problema esta vez. Recurro a la sabiduría de StackOverflow

Comment: Estás en StackOverflow en ESPAÑOL, [edit] tu pregunta por favor. [ask] - [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta mirar la sintaxis correcta del `case` en bash. Necesitas poner `;;` al terminar cada uno de las opciones que dispones.

El código se queda así...

```
case $OPCION in
        1) read -p "[+] Escriba el nombre del usuario: " username
        adduser $username
        echo ""
        echo -e "${BOLDGREEN}El usuario ${ENDCOLOR} ${yellowcolor}$username${ENDCOLOR} 
        ${BOLDGREEN}ha sido creado correctamente  ${ENDCOLOR}"
        echo ""
        ;;
        2) read -p "[+] Introduzca el nombre de usuario al que desea cambiar la 
        contraseña: " user
        passwd $user
        ;;
        3) read -p "[+] Introduzca el nombre del nuevo grupo:" gpapapap
        addgroup $gpapapap
        echo ""
        echo "[+] El grupo - $gpname - ha sido creado correctamente "
        echo ""
        ;;
esac
```